# Json Android: different activities or one class

Tags: android

I have a small doubt, I am developing an application with various activities that call a database via json, did right is to make calls in the same activity importing all packages in each activity or create an activity / service / class its functionality is the treatment of calls to the server?

Comment: You can have a class that deal with your information and will be consumed by your Activities, you don't need an activity to handle information, just send your context in the methods that require

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that exposes your required service methods, then use that class in each Activity to communicate w/your server.

Comment: As I thought, but all the examples I had seen what they did in each activity.